# OpenXML sheet cell value does not accept more than 15 zeroes

Tags: excel, xml, openxml, xlsx, openxml-sdk

I am doing XLSX generation and my program generates broken XLSX files. I am doing this with [ABAP XML transformations](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenabap_st.htm) but I believe the problem is more common and will be presented in any OpenXML generation tool.

I am speaking about sheet data files, which resides in `<file>.xlsx\xl\worksheets\` path of XLSX archive.

If the `sheet1.xml` file has a number with 16+ characters in cell value, i.e. `<v>` tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <dimension ref="A1:C6"/>
    <sheetViews>
        <sheetView workbookViewId="0">
            <selection activeCell="A1" sqref="A1"/>
        </sheetView>
    </sheetViews>
    <sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="12.75"/>
    <cols>
        <col min="1" max="16384" bestfit="1" width="15" customWidth="1" style="0" hidden="0" outlineLevel="0"/>
    </cols>
    <sheetData>
        <row r="1" spans="1:3 ">
            <c r="A1" s="5" t="s">
                <v>0</v>
            </c>
            <c r="B1" s="5" t="s">
                <v>0</v>
            </c>
            <c r="C1" s="5" t="s">
                <v>0</v>
            </c>
        </row>
        <row r="2" spans="1:3 ">
            <c r="A2">
                <v>0000000001</v>
            </c>
            <c r="B2" t="s">
                <v>1</v>
            </c>
            <c r="C2">
                <v>000000000000000000</v>
            </c>
        </row>
        <row r="3" spans="1:3 ">
            <c r="A3">
                <v>0000000003</v>
            </c>
            <c r="B3" t="s">
                <v>0</v>
            </c>
            <c r="C3">
                <v>000000000000000000</v>
            </c>
        </row>
    </sheetData>
    <pageMargins bottom="1" footer="0.5" header="0.5" left="0.75" right="0.75" top="1"/>
    <headerFooter alignWithMargins="0"/>
</worksheet>
```

it throws such an error

[image]

However, if I manually change the `sheet1.xml` inside the archive to 15 chars cell value

```
<c r="C2">
    <v>000000000000000</v>
</c>
```

and repack the archive, then the file is opened fine and this column automatically converted into number format. The same result is achieved if I change my XML transformation correspondingly in order to sent to XML alpha values, i.e. convert char values to numbers on-the-fly.

By inspecting [OpenXML format schemas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-xlsx/2c5dee00-eff2-4b22-92b6-0738acd4475e) I didn't find anything about such limitation.

Where this limitation come from?

Comment: Could this be a consequence of Excel's precision limit of 15 digits?

Comment: Don't know. Is this limit described in documentation?